# Examples of events that are neither pairwise independent nor mutually independent

Tags: probability

I've seen examples (more appropriately, counter-examples) which show that:

> Mutual independence does not imply pairwise independence and vice
>   versa.

I've tried looking around for examples where events are neither pairwise or mutually independent. I couldn't find any so I came up with some examples. To keep things simple, I restricted them to only 3 events. I began to think that at least one pair had to be disjoint (it's sufficient though) in order for the 3 events to be neither mutually or pairwise independent but this wasn't the case.

Question: Is it common for events to be neither mutually or pairwise independent?

Comment: Silly example: an event is $A$ always not independent with itself, so $A, A, A, A$ are neither pairwise or mutually independent.

Comment: Most examples are neither.  Though I would be interested in an example which  had mutually independent events but not pairwise independent events

Comment: (1) Mutual independence *does* imply pairwise independence, but not vice versa.  see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events esp. the last sentence in that section.  (2) It is really easy to come up with dependent events!  e.g. if $3$ events $X=Y=Z$ then they are all dependent (pairwise and mutually).  a less degenerate example: let $R$ be result of a 6-sided die roll and consider the events $R \ge 3, R \ge 4, R \ge 5$.

Comment: @Henry Check example 4 here https://faculty.washington.edu/fm1/394/Materials/2-3indep.pdf

Comment: @antkam Really? See the example in the notes I linked above.

Comment: @TomásPalamás Mutual independence of three events $A,B,C$ is **not just** $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) P(B) P(C)$, but also requires pairwise independence for each pair of events. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events): "Note that it is not a single condition involving only the product of all the probabilities of all single events; it must hold true for all subsets of events."

Comment: @TomásPalamás: Example 4 is not a case of mutual independence, and indeed your link shows $P(A∩B∩C^c) = \frac5{36}\not = \frac8{36} = P(A)\, P(B)\, P(C^c)$

Comment: @angryavian Got it. I missed that part in my book, I just read it. So, thats an example of neither mutual or pairwise independence.